# Processo automático em PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Queria saber qual a forma(e se é possível) de deixar algo automático ocorrendo em PHP. Minha ideia é, um site onde ele automaticamente coleta dados de outro site e armazena em um banco de dados só que automático, a cada determinado tempo por exemplo. O site ficaria hospedado em um servidor, onde sem precisar que alguém o acesse(um adm por exemplo), ele sempre iria coletar esses dados...

Comment: Talvez você queira pesquisar sobre *CRON jobs*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua solução é usando `cronjob` e poderá encontra-lo no cPanel normalmente no fundo da página.

Após abrindo a página, só terá de configurar o tempo que quer incrementar para a execução do ficheiro e submeter a localização onde o ficheiro se encontra no seu servidor.

Exemplo:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/ficheiro.php
```

Legenda:

```
[Minuto] [Hora] [Dia] [Mês] [Dia da Semana (0 = Domingo to 6 = Sábado)] [Comando]
```